# How to check if value exists in a database or not

Tags: vb.net

I want code in VB to check if values in a database exist or not.

Here is my code

```
conn.open()
Dim select As New OleDbCommand

select.Connection = conn

select.CommandText = " SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE field = textbox.value"
if count>0
MsgBox("already exists")

conn.close()
```

but it is not working.

Comment: This is just the possible text of your query. Please add the actual VB.NET code used to query the database

Comment: Use parameters...always.

Comment: this whole code  ... everyone here tells me to using parameters but unfortunately i don't know how  i prefer this method to implement my code

Comment: If you use this method, then a user can type something like `""; DROP TABLE your_table`in the textbox and delete the table. This is called an SQL Injection attack, and very common. Be safe and always use parameters.

Comment: @user2780962: It's not always about preferences, sometimes security has a higher priority -> parameters

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong, you don't put the textbox value inside the query in that way.
You should always use a parameterized query

```
Dim commandText = "SELECT count(*) from your_table where field = ?"
Using(conn = new OleDbConnection(.....)
Using(select = New OleDbCommand(commandText, conn)
    conn.open()
    select.Parameters.Add("@p1", textbox.value)
    Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(select.ExecuteScalar())
    if count > 0 Then
        MsgBox(" already exsist ")
    End If
End Using
End Using
```

Here you set the parameter placeholder (?) in the command text and add the parameter to the command with its value. After that you need to execute the command. In your case you need only a single value as your return from the command so the ExecuteScalar is the correct method to use.

Note also that the connection and the command are disposable objects and thus should be closed and disposed when you don't need them anymore. For this the correct approach is the [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

Comment: what i have to replace dots here Using(conn = new OleDbConnection(.....)    and what i have to write instead of questionmark

Comment: The question mark is the placeholder for the parameter in OleDb clients. (OleDb doesn't support named parameters like a SqlClient). You don't replace it. The dots in the creation of the OleDbConnection should be replaced by the connection string used to define the parameters needed to find your database. (You should have it somewhere in your code otherwise no connection is possible)

Comment: thank you steve, i'm still beginner , what " @ " means i can't understand this part of code select.parameters.add("@p1",textbox.vlaue) .. plz can you explain this

Comment: When you call AddWithValue you supply two params: The first is the name of the Parameter. In OleDb this is meaningless because OleDb use the position of the placeholder (?) to link the value to the correct field. So you could put any name there. `(@MyName, @MyParam, @p1)`. I have used this `@p1` just as a mnemonic (first parameters in the list of placeholders) and the `@` is a common way to call parameters when working with a SqlClient

Comment: You can read about [Parameterized Query here](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.2.shtml). It is a pretty old article (No AddWithValue at the time) and it is pretty easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE field = textbox.value"
```

Change it to

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_table WHERE field = '" & textbox.text & "'"
```

1) Winforms TextBox control dose not have a Value property. it has text property ( I am assuming you are using Textbox control)

2) You need to send the value contained in the Textbox.Text and not "TextBox.Value".  Hence you have add two string as mentioned in new query

3) **Then & endif**  is missing in your if statement

4) This is not the correct way to use the query as mentioned by @steve and others.

Comment: What if the textbox text contains a single quote? What if the textbox text contains `'xxxx);DROP TABLE your_table'--` Please never suggest to use string concatenation to build sql commands

Comment: You are right @Steve. But **OP** should also know that why his query did not work in the first place. I also think that **OP** is just a beginner. let him learn the basics first before bombarding with   conecepts **sql injections** etc when he makes very basic mistakes like one he made

Comment: @vcs i'm really beginner and i need a lot of help

Comment: And please where can i find full explain about parametrized queries

Comment: Read this (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
Public Sub insrt()
    con.Open()

    Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand("select count(*) from tbcat where catname=?", con)
    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@cat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtcourse.Text
    Dim count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd1.ExecuteScalar)
    If count > 0 Then
        MsgBox("Already Exist")
        'Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("insert into tbCat(Catcode,catname,protype)values('" & txtcode.Text & "','" & txtcourse.Text & "','" & txttype.Text & "')", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        'con.Close()
        display_course()

        txtcode.Text = String.Empty
        txtcourse.Text = String.Empty
    End If
    cmd1.Dispose()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```